# Telerik RadDatePicker not picking up dates post year 2030

Tags: asp.net, validation, telerik, date-formatting, raddatepicker

I am using RadDatePicker control for start and end date input controls on my form.
I am taking "01/01/1980" as min date and "12/31/2049" as max date. I am facing a problem when I enter the date manually in Date text box.

**Scenario 1:** I enter date as 123129. RadPicker correctly picks it up as 12/31/2029 and displays the formatted date value.
**Scenario 2:** I enter date as 123130. I get a client side validation warning. No matter what day and month I enter, it freezes every time on year greater than XX/XX/29 (2029).
**Scenario 3:** I enter date as 12312030 - complete year instead of just last 2 digits. RadPicker correctly picks it up as 12/31/2030 and displays the formatted date value.

I tested all 3 scenarios on [ASP.NET Calendar Demo - DatePicker - First Look](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/custompopup/defaultcs.aspx)  as well.

I am not sure why the validation kicks in even when the max date is set as 12/31/2049.
 Please assist me in resolving this issue.

Thanks,
Vaibhav

Comment: I think you found a bug in Telerik DLLs.

btw: do you have to enter dates with MMDDYY format for some reason or you just want to find the reason of this behaviour?

Comment: @Andreaoid: That was very much my initial reaction as I tested out the RadDatePicker control thoroughly. 
Regarding input format, this is one of the requirements mentioned in issue description. Our testing team (accidentally) found out that entering dates without '/' also works... :)

Comment: Yes, for some reason they don't accept MMDDYY even if the range is < 100 years... it's surely a bug in the checking procedure. :)

Comment: I have raised a support ticket with Telerik. I'll share the solution/comments once I hear anything from them.

Comment: Finally I got a solution from them. As per Telerik experts:  
The problem experienced is caused by the fact that years starting from 30 and greater are parsed as 19XX. This means that 123129 will be parsed as 12/31/2029 and 123130 will be parsed as 12/31/1930. Now this is an invalid date because the default value of the MinDate property is 1/1/1980. Setting the 'ShortYearCenturyEnd' property of the DateInput to 2099 resolves the problem.  
`<telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="Picker1" MinDate="" DateInput-ShortYearCenturyEnd="2099"></telerik:RadDatePicker>`

Comment: Good. I suggest you to post your own answer and accept it to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

"The years starting from 30 and greater are parsed as 19.. like if u say 30th(year) it would get it like 1930, 123130 will be parsed as 12/31/1930. this is invalid because the default value of the MinDate i.e. 1/1/1980.
In Order to solve this set the ShortYearCenturyEnd property of the DateInput to 2099.

Hope i answered the question.